# How to increase a number every time a function is run?

Tags: python

So here's what I want to do right now. Simply put I am currently working on a card game and the way I have the game pick the cards for the AI is like this:

1. Make a list containing all the available cards, sorted by the damage (Lowest to highest). Let's call this list 'ai_list'
2. Set the card that will be placed (enemy_card) to ai_list[index]. 'index' being the number I want to increase by one every time the function is run.

So I currently have the game execute in turns (player-enemy-player-enemy...), but the problem is that I don't know how to increase the index (set to 0 in the beginning) every time the function for the AI's card placing runs.

How can I do this?

Comment: Use a global variable. A local variable will reset every time the function is run. Many people (with good reason) frown on global variables, but they are often a natural way to keep track of a game state.

Comment: I copy-pasted your question's exact title into a Google search and the resulting duplicate question was in the top five results. You are expected to perform at least a few seconds of research before posting a new question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Seems like you want to count the number of times a function is being called. You can use a very simple decorator for that:

```
def count(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        wrapper.counter += 1    # executed every time the wrapped function is called
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    wrapper.counter = 0         # executed only once in decorator definition time
    return wrapper

@count
def func():
    pass

print(func.counter)
# 0
func()
print(func.counter)
# 1
func()
print(func.counter)
# 2
```

Answer (score 0):

why not using a global?
something like:

```
index = 0
def func(..)

     global index
     index+=1
```

Comment: I heard using globals in general is bad practice, so I'm trying to avoid them as much as I can.

Comment: What if you have 5 functions you want to count? Will you create 5 global variables?